# Spring Boot Application: Direct urls are not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

When the user navigates to any URL like `https://myexample.com/myurl` he gets below error

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

`Apache Tomcat/8.5.38`

However URL Like `https://myexample.com` is working fine and `shows welcome page` of our application and from Application menu all url navigation works perfectly fine. but if you hit direct url on browser it throws above mentioned error.
Let me know if any other information is needed.

I am not able to reproduce the issue on my local environment

Can this code be the cause of of the above issue ?

```
 @Bean
    public ErrorPageFilter errorPageFilter() {
        return new ErrorPageFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean disableSpringBootErrorFilter(ErrorPageFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(11);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
```

Comment: show the corresponding request handler or controller for that request

Comment: Share your Controller and related code

Answer (score 0):

You have no registered controller that server this path. You should have component annotated something like this

```
@Controller
class MyController(){

  @GetMapping("/myurl"){
   public void myHandler(whatever args here){
          body.....
   }
       ..
   }
}
```

Comment: We do have respective controller for all the urls , we just removed  ErrorPageFilter  and FilterRegistrationBean and all urls works fine.